# Question About Rules Of Irrational Exponent.

Tags: real-numbers, exponentiation

> let $b$ be a real number, and let $b_1, b_2, b_3, \dots$ be an infinite sequence of *rational* numbers such that the sequence $(b_n)$ has limit $b$.  It can be shown that the sequence $(a^{b_n})$ has a limit, which is independent of the particular sequence $(b_n)$ that we have chosen, as long as the sequence has $b$ as a limit.
>
> Then for $a\gt 0$ we can define $a^b$ as the limit of the sequence $(a^{b_n})$.

For $r ,s$ irrational  and $a\gt0$ I want to prove
$$ (a^{r}) ^s=a^{rs}$$

Let $a_n\to r$ and $b_m \to s$ are sequence  of rational. then
$$  (a^{r}) ^s=\lim_{m \to \infty} \left \{ \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}  a^{a_n} \right)^{bm} \right\}$$

Now from just first step  I don't know what to do .Any hints on this ?